Proving a specific solution vector of the characteristic polynomial is a cyclic vector in linear algebra
I am working on a problem in linear algebra involving the characteristic polynomial of a matrix. The problem I encountered is as follows:
Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $K$, with the characteristic polynomial $f(\lambda) = P_1(\lambda)P_2(\lambda) \cdots P_k(\lambda)$, where each $P_i(\lambda)$ $(1 \leq i \leq k)$ is a distinct monic irreducible polynomial over $K$.
Suppose $\alpha_i$ is a non-zero solution to the equation $P_i(A)x = 0$. Prove that $\alpha = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k$ is a cyclic vector for $A$ in the cyclic space $K^n$.
My current understanding is as follows:

I know how to prove $K^n$ is a cyclic space.
The matrix $A$ has $n$ different eigenvalues over $ℂ$, and I can figure out this case rather than over $K$(i.e. $f(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n)$).
The factorization of the characteristic polynomial might indicate different eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ and their corresponding eigenspaces.
Since $\alpha_i$ is a solution to $P_i(A)x = 0$, $\alpha_i$ may lie in the eigenspace corresponding to $P_i$.
The basic idea might be to prove $\alpha, A\alpha, A^2\alpha, \cdots,A^{n-1}\alpha$ are linearly independent.

However, I am unsure how to combine these observations to prove that $\alpha$ is a cyclic vector.
My approach so far has been to directly analyze the definition of a cyclic vector, but I have not yet arrived at a clear proof.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to prove this or any hints or theorems that might be useful.
Note:
Cyclic Subspace and Cyclic Vector
For a given vector $v$ and matrix $A$, the cyclic subspace is the smallest invariant subspace generated by $v$, which is formally expressed as
$$
\text{span}\{v, Av, A^2v, \dots\}
$$
The cyclic subspace consists of all linear combinations of the vectors generated by the action of the matrix $A$ on the vector $v$.And $v$ is called cyclic vector over the cyclic subspace.
Cyclic Space
Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and a vector $v$ in the vector space $K^n$ (where $K$ is a field), if the subspace generated by the vector $v$,
$$
\text{span}\{v, Av, A^2v, \dots, A^{n-1}v\}
$$
equals the entire vector space $K^n$, then the vector space $k^n$ is called the cyclic space.
In other words, a cyclic space is defined as the entire vector space generated through the action of the matrix $A$ on a cyclic vector.

What is the definition of a cyclic vector? (What is the definition of a cyclic space?)

@Gerry Myerson, I have attached the definition of Cyclic Space and Cyclic Vector.

The problem can be approached using a straightforward strategy. As mentioned above, the goal is to prove that the set $$\{\alpha, A\alpha, \ldots, A^{n-1}\alpha\}$$ is linearly independent.
Let$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i A^{i-1}\alpha = 0$, and we need to show that $l_i = 0$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.
Step 1: Proving $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is linearly independent
First, consider the set $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$, where $P_i(A)\alpha_i = 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$.
Since the characteristic polynomial $f(\lambda)$ factors as $f(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^k P_i(\lambda)$, where the elements of the  set $\{P_i(\lambda)\}_{i=1}^k$ are coprime, the vector space $V$ can be decomposed as:
$$
V = \ker P_1(A) \oplus \ker P_2(A) \oplus \cdots \oplus \ker P_k(A),
$$
where $\alpha_i \in \ker P_i(A)$. Therefore, the set $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is linearly independent.
Step 2: Proving $\{\alpha, A\alpha, \ldots, A^{n-1}\alpha\}$ is linearly independent
Next, we prove that $\{\alpha, A\alpha, \ldots, A^{n-1}\alpha\}$ is linearly independent:
The linear combination of $\{A^{j-1}\alpha\}_{j=1}^n$ can be rewritten as a combination of $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n l_j (A^{j-1}\alpha) = \sum_{j=1}^n l_j \sum_{i=1}^k A^{j-1}\alpha_i 
= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k l_j A^{j-1} \alpha_i 
= \sum_{i=1}^k \left(\sum_{j=1}^n l_j A^{j-1}\right) \alpha_i.
$$
Since $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is linearly independent, if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i A^{i-1}\alpha = 0$, then $\sum_{j=1}^n l_j A^{j-1} = 0$.
Step 3: Utilizing the diagonalizability of $A$
It is also known that $A$ is diagonalizable over the complex field (this can be verified independently). Thus, $A$ can be decomposed as:
$$
A = P \Lambda P^{-1},
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix. Substituting this into the equation, we get:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n l_j \Lambda^{j-1} = 0.
$$
Since $A$ is not a null matrix, neither is $\Lambda$. Therefore, it must be that $l_i = 0$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.
Conclusion
Thus, we have proved the linear independence of the set $\{\alpha, A\alpha, \ldots, A^{n-1}\alpha\}$.
Q.E.D.
